# How do I draw a pentagram in made up of of arrows in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have been trying to emulate this picture for an app I am building:

[image: target]

I managed to figure out how to build a pentagram, but of course the path is made up of continuous lines.

```
import SwiftUI

struct Pentagram : Shape {
   var sides = 5

   func path(in rect : CGRect ) -> Path{
        let center = CGPoint(x: rect.width / 2, y: rect.height / 2)
        let radius = rect.width / 2

       //get angle in radians, then double it because we want to skip the first vertex and go to the next
        let angle = Double.pi * 2 / Double(sides) * 2
        var path = Path()
        var startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        
       for side in 0 ..< (sides + 1) {
           
           let x = center.x + CGFloat(cos(Double(side) * angle)) * CGFloat (radius)
           let y = center.y + CGFloat(sin(Double(side) * angle)) * CGFloat(radius)
           
           let vertexPoint = CGPoint( x: x, y: y)
           
           if (side == 0) {
               startPoint = vertexPoint
               path.move(to: startPoint )
           }
           else {
               path.addLine(to: vertexPoint)
           }
       }
       
        return path
  }
}

struct Arrow: Shape {
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var shape = Path()
        let arrowCapWidth = 0.3
        let maxLength = rect.maxX * 0.9
        let h = (((2 * maxLength) + 1) / 4).squareRoot()
        
        //WOOD (x ; y)
        let woodX = rect.minX
        let woodY = rect.minY + h
        
        //WOOD/EARTH (x ; y)
        let earthX = maxLength
        let earthY = rect.minY + h
        //arrowcap
        let arrowCapX = maxLength * 0.95
        let topArrowCapY = woodY * (1 - arrowCapWidth)
        let bottomArrowCapY = woodY * (1 + arrowCapWidth)
        
        //WOOD -> EARTH
        //line
        shape.move(to: CGPoint(x: woodX, y: woodY))
        shape.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: earthX, y: earthY))
        
//        arrow tip
        shape.move(to: CGPoint(x: earthX, y: earthY))
        shape.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: arrowCapX, y: topArrowCapY))
        shape.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: arrowCapX, y: bottomArrowCapY))
        shape.closeSubpath()
        
        
        
    
        return shape
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            Text("Drawing practice")
            Arrow()
                .stroke(.black, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 3, lineJoin: .miter))
            Pentagram()
                .stroke(.black, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 3, lineJoin: .miter))
                .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: -17))
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

[image: Resulting image]

I have 2 approaches in mind, but I can't see to progress with either, so I wanted to ask more experience coders for their input:

1. Use the arrow code I made and make a new image that uses the arrow 5 times at particular angles
2. Use the pentagram and make the sides shorter, and append an arrowhead to one side of each line. This picture shows the approach I was thinking about:

[image: Consruction]

I'm good at math, so finding the starting point and vertex of each arrow is simply finding there the lines intersect the smaller circle, but I can't seem to work it out, and frankly, my approach is likely to be more complicated than it needs to be. Eventually, I might like the arrow to be slightly curved, so I also tried to play around with "addArc" and "addCurve", but I didn't get anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

I would go for the first approach you suggested. If you have an arrow `Shape`, you can draw it 5 times inside a `ZStack`, with different `.rotationEffect` and `.offset`.

The items that the arrows are pointing to can be super-imposed over the `ZStack` as multiple `.overlay` with different alignments. You might want to use `.top`, `.topLeading`, `.topTrailing`, `.bottomLeading` and `.bottomTrailing` alignments.

The example below shows how the basic pentagon arrangement can be achieved in this way. I've used a different arrow shape to the one you provided - it has a curved line like in your original picture:

```swift
struct Arrow: Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        let unit = rect.width / 8.0
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX + unit, y: rect.minY + unit))
        path.addQuadCurve(
            to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX + unit, y: rect.maxY - unit),
            control: CGPoint(x: rect.minX + (unit * 2), y: rect.midY)
        )
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX + unit, y: rect.minY + (unit * 5)))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX + unit, y: rect.minY + unit))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX - unit, y: rect.minY + (unit * 7)))
        return path
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    private var arrow: some View {
        Arrow()
            .stroke(style: .init(lineWidth: 15, lineCap: .butt, lineJoin: .miter))
            .foregroundColor(.red.opacity(0.1))
            .frame(width: 60, height: 250)
    }

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            arrow.rotationEffect(.degrees(18)).offset(x: -60)
            arrow.rotationEffect(.degrees(162)).offset(x: 60)
            arrow.rotationEffect(.degrees(90)).offset(y: -40)
            arrow.rotationEffect(.degrees(234)).offset(x: 30, y: 60)
            arrow.rotationEffect(.degrees(306)).offset(x: -30, y: 60)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Pentagon]

I just arranged the arrows in this example by eye, with your math skills I expect you will be able to work out the offsets more precisely!

Answer (score 0):

For the third approach, You can add arrowheads to the Pentagram and add some curves to this arrowheads just like the code below:

```
import SwiftUI

struct PentagramWithSpaces: Shape {
    var sides = 5
    var gapAngle: Angle = .degrees(36) // Angle between the points

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        let center = CGPoint(x: rect.width / 2, y: rect.height / 2)
        let radius = rect.width / 2

        var path = Path()

        for i in 0..<sides {
            let angle = gapAngle * Double(i)
            let x = center.x + CGFloat(cos(angle.radians)) * radius
            let y = center.y - CGFloat(sin(angle.radians)) * radius

            if i == 0 {
                path.move(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: y))
            } else {
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: y))
            }

            // Add curved arrows at the endpoints
            if i == sides - 1 {
                let arrowTipX = center.x + CGFloat(cos(angle.radians + .pi / 10)) * (radius - 10)
                let arrowTipY = center.y - CGFloat(sin(angle.radians + .pi / 10)) * (radius - 10)
                let controlX = center.x
                let controlY = center.y - radius
                path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: arrowTipX, y: arrowTipY), control: CGPoint(x: controlX, y: controlY))
            }
        }

        path.closeSubpath()

        return path
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Pentagram with Spaces")
            PentagramWithSpaces()
                .stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 3)
                .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

The `gapAngle` determines the angular separation between the points. Adjusting this angle will change the amount of space between the corners.

Answer (score 0):

```
  import SwiftUI
    
    struct Pentagram: Shape {
        func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
            let center = CGPoint(x: rect.width / 2, y: rect.height / 2)
            let radius = rect.width / 2
            let angleIncrement = 2.0 * .pi / 5.0
            var angle = -CGFloat.pi / 10.0 // Start from the top vertex
            
            var path = Path()
            var points: [CGPoint] = []
            
            for _ in 0..<5 {
                let x = center.x + cos(angle) * radius
                let y = center.y + sin(angle) * radius
                points.append(CGPoint(x: x, y: y))
                angle += 2 * angleIncrement // Skip one vertex
            }
            
            // Draw the pentagram
            path.move(to: points[0])
            for i in 1..<5 {
                path.addLine(to: points[i])
            }
            path.closeSubpath()
            
            // Append arrows
            for i in 0..<5 {
                let startPoint = points[i]
                let endPoint = points[(i + 1) % 5]
                let arrowLength: CGFloat = 30.0 // Adjust as needed
                let arrowWidth: CGFloat = 10.0 // Adjust as needed
                
                let dx = endPoint.x - startPoint.x
                let dy = endPoint.y - startPoint.y
                let length = sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)
                
                let ux = dx / length
                let uy = dy / length
                
                let arrowStartX = startPoint.x + ux * (length - arrowLength)
                let arrowStartY = startPoint.y + uy * (length - arrowLength)
                
                path.move(to: CGPoint(x: arrowStartX, y: arrowStartY))
                path.addLine(to: endPoint)
                
                let arrowTip1 = CGPoint(x: arrowStartX - uy * arrowWidth, y: arrowStartY + ux * arrowWidth)
                let arrowTip2 = CGPoint(x: arrowStartX + uy * arrowWidth, y: arrowStartY - ux * arrowWidth)
                
                path.move(to: arrowTip1)
                path.addLine(to: endPoint)
                path.addLine(to: arrowTip2)
            }
            
            return path
        }
    }
    
    struct ContentView: View {
        var body: some View {
            VStack {
                Text("Drawing practice")
                Pentagram()
                    .stroke(.black, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 3, lineJoin: .miter))
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
    
    struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
```

**This is close to what you want to do. In 5 steps "A pentagram also has 5 vertices ;) "**

**Step 1**

The Pentagram struct’s path(in:) function starts by calculating the center and radius of the circle in which the pentagram is inscribed.

The angleIncrement is calculated as 2π/5 since a pentagram has 5 vertices

initialize the starting angle to point to the top vertex of the pentagram

An array points is created to hold the vertices of the pentagram

**Step 2**

A loop is run 5 times (for 5 vertices), and for each iteration, it calculates the x y position for a vertex and stores it in the points array.
For every iteration, the angle is incremented by double the angleIncrement to skip one vertex, thus forming a pentagram.

**Step 3**

after acalculating the vertices, the path is moved to the first vertex, and lines are drawn to the rest of the vertices to form the pentagram. Finally, path.closeSubpath() closes the path to complete the pentagram.

**Step 4**

For each side of the pentagram, an arrow is appended.
It calculates the start point of the arrow on each side by moving a certain length (arrowLength) from the end vertex towards the start vertex.
It also calculates two points arrowTip1 and arrowTip2 to form the arrowhead by moving perpendicular to the direction of the arrow from the start point of the arrow.
Lines are drawn to form the arrow from the start point of the arrow to the end vertex and from the arrow tips to the end vertex.

**Step 5**

The Pentagram shape is then used within a ContentView and applied with a stroke to render the final pentagram with arrows.
The ContentView struct is where the Pentagram shape is integrated into the user interface, and you can see the final output of the shape.